# How do I implement strcpy function in C++

Tags: c++

So I have this header given to me

```
int mystrcpy(char *c, const char* s);
```

And I have to implement strcpy function myself. But when I do it and run the program, the console stops working, which I believe is a sign of memory address violation.

I tried this:

```
int mystrcpy(char *c, const char* s)
{
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<strlen(s);i++)
        c[i]=s[i];
    c[++i]=NULL;
    cout<<c;
    return 0;
}
```

Full code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
class Persoana
{
 char *nume;
 int an;
 float inaltime;
public:
 int my_strcpy(char *c, const char*s);
};


int Persoana::my_strcpy(char *c, const char* s)
{

 //code I need to insert

 return 0;
}

int main()
{
 Persoana a;
 cout << endl;
 cout<<a.my_strcpy("maria","george");

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: why do you have to write your own `strcpy`? just asking, because using `strlen` seems to be fine

Comment: btw do you want to learn "c++ the c way" ? because if not then you should take a look at `std::string` first

Comment: Exercise: find out why `for(i=0;i<strlen(s);i++)` is inefficient.

Comment: If that is a stab at writing a function definition then take the ";" off of the end of the header...

Comment: Don't use NULL for 0, only for pointers

Comment: @HangrY Don't even use it for pointers, use `nullptr` instead

Comment: `int mystrcpy(char *c, const char* s) { std::strcpy(c, s); return 0; }`

Comment: Canonical strcpy take only one pass over the source :  `while(*s) {*c++ = *s++; }  *c = 0;`

Comment: Please read about [mcve]. In the code you show here we cannot know where `c` points to, so basically anything is possible even if the method was fine otherwise

Comment: I have to implement strcpy cuz it is a school assignment, ok?

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux `while(*c++ = *s++);` takes care of the null terminator for you

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux -- it's usually even more compact than that: `while (*c++ = *s++) ;`. Yes, I know, busybody compilers will give you various warnings about this code.

Comment: @JohnDoe *I have to implement strcpy cuz it is a school assignment, ok?* -- If you are doing that, then why are you using `strlen`, since that is found in the same family of C-string functions?  I would expect you can't use `strlen` either.

Comment: Sort out the formatting of the code. Always use braces/ Learn to write readable code

Comment: @JohnDoe could you show us a part of your code where char * is declared and function mystrcpy is called?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie why would the usage of strlen be a concern? You deviate from the point.

Comment: @JohnDoe please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the actual problem you are trying to solve. Your `mystrcpy` has a logic bug that trashes memory, which may be amplified if the calling code uses `mystrcpy` incorrectly to begin with.

Comment: The `strlen` is called for each character in the string. `strlen` requires `n` operations. And this is called n times - i.e n*n operations will be performed. When you can do the task in n operations

Comment: Imagine "How do I implement `strlen` function in C++". Then you would know why calling `strlen` so many times in `strcpy` is a silly idea.

Comment: @JohnDoe -- Here is the issue -- you posted code claiming you want to write your own `strcpy`.  You give absolutely no parameters in what you can or can't use.  Since you didn't state what you can or can't use, it is assumed that you can't use *any* C-string related function.  This includes `strcat`, `strlen`, `strchr`, and included in that `strcpy`.  Otherwise, why not use `memcpy` and stick a null at the end?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie anything would do as long as I dont use the strcpy function itself. Even library functions

Comment: Now, you suddenly mention a member function `Persoana::my_strcpy`. Your question is less consistent now. Not to mention how to make sense of making a `strcpy` replica a member function.

Comment: @NickyC - The whole exercise (if it is a student exercise) makes little sense. Most likely an ivy league university!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other posters have posted implementations of `strcpy` - Why you are using this in C++ code? That is an interesting question as C++ very rarely uses C style strings

The other problem is with its usage:

```
int main()
{
 Persoana a;
 cout << endl;
 cout<<a.my_strcpy("maria","george");

 return 0;
}
```

The strings "maria" and "george" are read only. Instead create an empty read/ write string as shown below that is long enough - i.e. 7 characters (do not forget the null character)

So the code should be

```
int main()
{
 Persoana a;
 char copy_of_string[7];
 cout << endl;
 cout<<a.my_strcpy(copy_of_string,"george");

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: @JohnDoe - Please re-read peoples comments - and think about them

Answer (score 0):

Your loop itself is OK (but inefficient, since you call `strlen()` on every iteration).  The real problem is when you go to insert the null terminator at the end of the copied string.  You are incrementing `i` again before inserting the terminator.  DON'T do that.  `i` is already at the correct index after the loop ends, so just use it as-is:

```
int mystrcpy(char *c, const char* s);
{
    int i, len = strlen(s);
    for(i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        c[i] = s[i];
    c[i] = '\0'; // <-- NO ++ HERE!
    cout << c;
    return 0;
}
```

That being said, the simplest way to implement `strcpy` without using `i` at all is as follows:

```
int mystrcpy(char *c, const char* s)
{
    char *p = c;
    while (*p++ = *s++);
    cout << c;
    return 0;
}
```

If you remove the `cout` then it becomes simpler:

```
int mystrcpy(char *c, const char* s)
{
    while (*c++ = *s++);
    return 0;
}
```

No matter what, make sure that when you call `mystrcpy()`, `c` is pointing to a `char[]` buffer that is allocated to at least `strlen(s)+1` chars in size, otherwise the code will have *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score -2):

The for loop

```
for(i=0; i < strlen(s); i++)
```

aborts when *i < strlen(s)* becomes *false*, which is the case when i is equal to *strlen(s)*. So that will be the value of i when the loop ends.

C strings are NULL-terminated as you know, so you need *strlen(s) + 1* bytes reserved for c. Since you increment i again before writing the '\0' character, you're using *strlen(s) + 2* bytes starting at c.

If c is exactly the size that's needed (*strlen(s) + 1*), that *may* lead to an access violation, since you're writing past the end of the allocated memory.

So instead of

```
c[++i]=NULL;
```

write

```
c[i]='\0';
```

Hope this makes sense!

Comment: "*that will lead to an access violation*" - no, it leads to a buffer overflow that results in undefined behavior, which MAY throw an AV, or it may just trash memory without crashing